# Displaying a view when clicking a item in listview

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-listview, bundle

I have this listview which is a list of news items. I want to display a detailed version of a particular news item when that news item is clicked in the listview.

So far i was able to create the listview and display the news items in a listview. (NOTE: news items are taken from a JSON)

I was able to display a view when a news item is clicked in the listview. but the PROBLEM is when a listview item is clicked, a view of detailed version of news items is displayed BUT it shows all the detailed version of news.

I WANT TO SHOW ONLY THE DETAILED VERSION OF THE NEWS ITEM THAT WAS CLICKED. how can i do this?

after researching i think i should use a bundle for this.but i have no idea how to do this.

I'll post my classes here

NewsFragment.java

```
public class NewsFramgment extends Fragment {


    private ListView listView;


    private ArrayList<BaseElement> News;
    private LazyAdapter adapter;
    private Activity activity;
    private CommonVariable commonVariable;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_fragment, container,
                false);

        activity = this.getActivity();

        commonVariable = (CommonVariable) activity.getApplication();


        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                 int position, long id)

               {


              android.support.v4.app.Fragment detail = new NewsDetailFragment();
              android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
              fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, detail).addToBackStack("back").commit(); 

                }
              });



            new BackGround().execute();

        return view;
    }


public class BackGround extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            News = JSONServices.getNewsDescription();
            return null;
        } 



        @Override
        /* check again */
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            commonVariable.setNewsDescription(News);

            adapter = new LazyAdapter(News, activity,Element.NEWS_LIST.getType());

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

    }


}
```

NewsDetailFramgment.java

```
public class NewsDetailFragment extends Fragment {

private View view1;

    private ArrayList<BaseElement> newsdetail;
    private LazyAdapter adapter;
    private Activity activity;
    private CommonVariable commonVariable;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsdetail_fragment, container,
                false);

        activity = this.getActivity();

        commonVariable = (CommonVariable) activity.getApplication();

        view1 = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.list);


        new BackGround().execute();

        return view;
    }


public class BackGround extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {



            newsdetail = JSONServices.getNewsDescription();

            return null;

        } 



        @Override
        /* check again */
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            commonVariable.setTheater(newsdetail);

            adapter = new LazyAdapter(newsdetail, activity,Element.NEWS_DETAIL.getType());

            ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) view1).setAdapter(adapter);

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: there is example in the docs http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: @dtheo you will have a list of news in one fragment and on clikc of item you will see the news in detail in another fragment that is the point

Comment: @dtheo no need for that. See the docs. You can design in such a way you make a call to the server when you want detail news

Comment: @dtheo no need. I posted a link to the docs which shows how to use interface as a call back to the activity. Rest it upto the user to design

Comment: in that example id article_fragment is not available

Comment: `article_fragment` is a reference to the way that the example identifies the Fragment. In your case you could just create a new instance of your detail fragment - `NewsDetailFramgment articleFrag = new NewsDetailFragment();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're calling `newsdetail = JSONServices.getNewsDescription();` and then assigning that result to your `adapter` in `NewsDetailFragment`. What is being returned by `JSONServices.getNewsDescription();`? I imagine it is all of the NewsDetail articles.

@Raghunandan is right, the example shows how to handle two fragments in an activity and show the 'Detail' fragment based on which item was selected in the 'News' list.

You could implement the calls in your parent Activity as shown in the example under 'Implement the Interface'.

YourParentActivity.java

```
public static class YourParentActivity extends Activity {

    implements NewsFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{
        ...
    }

    public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
        NewsDetailFramgment articleFrag = (NewsDetailFramgment)
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.news_detail_framgment);

        if (articleFrag != null) {
            // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

            // Call a method in the NewsDetailFramgment to update its content
            articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);
        } else {
            // Otherwise, we're in the one-pane layout and must swap frags...

            // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
            NewsDetailFramgment newFragment = new NewsDetailFramgment ();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(NewsDetailFramgment.ARG_POSITION, position);
            newFragment.setArguments(args);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that `onArticleSelected()` accepts `int position`? This is the position in the News Headlines adapter that was clicked. You can use this to get the corresponding News Detail item from your Details result.

This is purely an outline based on the example, but should show you what you need to do in your parent activity.

Read the example and add the relevant parts to your fragments (look at 'Define an Interface' for changes to your `NewsFragment.java`).

**Edit**

You need to define an interface in your `NewsFragment` class as shown in the documentation under 'Define an Interface'.

```
// Container Activity must implement this interface
public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
    public void onArticleSelected(int position);
}
```

This provides a callback to your parent class to handle when a news headline is pressed with the position of the headline which was selected. In the example it calls `onArticleSelected(int position);` in your parent activity to then populate the `NewsDetailFragment`.

Comment: I'm not extending my class to a Activity.I extend it to a fragment.Does it change things?

Comment: Well, you would need to have a parent activity which hosts the two fragments.

Comment: [The documentation on fragments ]( http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) explains how a fragment is really just a portion of a parent activity, being either ui or behavior.

Comment: What is the difference between ListFragment and Fragment. Because in that code it has extended it's HeadlineFragment to a ListFragment. But in my code i have extended it to a Fragment and i was able to get the listview. Is it necessary to extend it to a ListFragment ,because i tried and some errors came up

Comment: You don't have to, you can implement it manually like in your code, but if it's primary purpose is to hold a listView, then there are some benefits to extending that class.

Comment: Thank you.and one more question.In that sample code

 try {
             mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
         } catch (ClassCastException e) {
             throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                     + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");


What is this must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener means?